# Openshift imagestream "Import failed (Unauthorized)" for private external secure registry

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-origin

May be I'm not getting something right, but my ImageStream returnes "**! error: Import failed (Unauthorized): you may not have access to the Docker image "my_registry:5000/project/my_image:latest"**".

I have set up all needed steps to connect to external registry (created secret and added it to current projects's serviceaccount/default and serviceaccount/builder accounts). All deploymentconfigs with specified `image: my_registry:5000/project/my_image:latest` are working great, node can successfully pull the image and create a pod.

But when I am making image stream with:

```
from:
      kind: DockerImage
      name: my_registry:5000/project/my_image:latest
```

I get error that I am not authorised.

So what am i doing wrong? Is there any additional account I should give rights for pull?

```
 oc describe sa/builder
Name:           builder
Namespace:      nginx
Labels:         <none>

Image pull secrets:     builder-dockercfg-8ogvt
                        my_registry

Mountable secrets:      builder-token-v6w8q
                        builder-dockercfg-8ogvt
                        my_registry

Tokens:                 builder-token-0j8p5
                        builder-token-v6w8q
```

and

```
oc describe sa/default
Name:           default
Namespace:      nginx
Labels:         <none>

Image pull secrets:     default-dockercfg-wmm1h
                            my_registry

Mountable secrets:      default-token-st7k9
                        default-dockercfg-wmm1h

Tokens:                 default-token-m2aoq
                        default-token-st7k9
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends upon your particular infrastructure configuration, but here are some pointers which worked for me -

1. Assuming your private external registry has Certificates, please check if those certificates are properly imported, if thats not the case, then please add the registry as insecure.
2. Docker pull, build config, imagestream pull - all work in different manner.
3. Also it is recommended that pull secret name should be same as hostname of registry authentication endpoint. (If not using insecure registry).
4. For ex. Registry FQDN Name:5000/yourapp:latest (Certificates need this to work properly).

Please take a look [here](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/managing_images.html#allowing-pods-to-reference-images-from-other-secured-registries)

```
oc secrets link default <pull_secret_name> --for=pull
```

Comment: Thank you for response! I do have private registry with Certificates, and they are properly impoted (otherwise I wouldn't be able to make docker pull) - but maybe i need to import them somehow to openshift, and trust on the hosts's operating system is not enough?

Comment: The secret name is the sane as FQDN.  I am using oc secrets link - it does not help(( Can you please  specify how deployment config pull differs from imagestream pull?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when I was trying to import an image from a docker registry hosted in another Openshift cluster. After some debugging I found the problem: **Unable to find a secret to match https://docker-dev.xxxx.com:443/openshift/token (docker-dev.xxxx.com:443/openshift/token)**

The Openshift Docker registry is using the OAuth of Openshift. So you have to create a secret where the `--docker-server` is pointing to the `/openshift/token` endpoint. eg:

```
oc secrets new-dockercfg registry.example.com \
    --docker-server=https://registry.example.com:443/openshift/token \
    --docker-username=default/puller-sa \
    --docker-password=<token> \
    --docker-email=someone@example.com
```